# Sorting ranges of numbers to find one range that covers the values of the others using python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

So my problem is that I have hundreds of **min.** to **max.** ranges. I want to find the numberrange that most of them are in.

For example: `0,5 - 2,5 ; 2 - 3 ; 0,2 - 4` All of these numbers have one range that covers all of them. I want to find these Ranges to cover most of the different ranges with one. Basically my program has to group them and categorise them into "masterranges". Ideal solution would be that i can use only few ranges but can be sure that I also cover the ranges of others.

If you have any Ideas or can recommend tools to get there using python I would be happy and thankful for your help since I am new to programming.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: "cover most of the different ranges with one": how would one determine if this criteria is met?

Comment: For the example you provided, what would be the answer?  Also, please indicate what 0,5 means - I assume that you are in a locale where the  comma is a decimal so 0,5 is one half.

Comment: One possibility would be to treat gaps (outside of all input ranges) as the start and end of a "master range". For example if you had "0-3; 2-4; 5-7" then the answer would be "0-4; 5-7". This at least would be a well-posed problem. If you want this, or any other variant, I suggest you edit the question quickly before it gets closed.

Comment: Hey I am sorry I think my example was misleading. If you graph all of the ranges in a chart you can see that there is an Area that covers all of the ranges. 2 - 2,5. applying that range includes all other ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only looking for a simple graphic representation to get a feel of the distribution of the intevals you can simply use a plot with transparent lines to indicate highly puplicated intervalls and vise versa.

For example as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

intervals = [[0.5, 1.5],
             [2,3],
             [0.2,4]]

for int in intervals:
    plt.plot(int,[0,0], 'b', alpha = 0.2, linewidth = 100)

plt.show()
```

Giving the following result:

[image]

Clearly indication that the intervall 1.5-2 is highly populated. I now see that I failed to copy your intervalls correctly but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thank you for your help:)  I will try to apply that to my data set. If I see a couple Areas highly populated I can use these Areas to detect my main ranges

Comment: @Johannes You can mark the question as answered with the green checkmark next to the correct answer to indicate the question is solved.

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

intervals = [[3.6,4.5],
             [3.6,4.5],
             [7.8,9.6],
             [7.9,9.6], 
             [7.8,9.6],
             [3.4,4.1],
             [2.8,3.4],
            ]

for int in intervals:
    plt.plot(int,[0,0], 'b', alpha = 0.2, linewidth = 100)

plt.show()`